# Different module components communication in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have One component and I want it to pass data to another one which is in another module. Actually my `app.component` is a parent of these children modules. And I want each child module to send some data to `app.component`. But they are children and parent only in a sence of routing. So they aren't actually parents and children, I guess.

I mean, my templet for `app.component` looks like this:

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a routerLink="link1" routerLinkActive="active">Page1</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="link2" routerLinkActive="active">Page2</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="link3" routerLinkActive="active">Page3</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="link4" routerLinkActive="active">Page4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div *ngIf="needsSidebar" id="sidebar">some content</div>
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

So `app.component` has no direct connection with these modules and theirs components. I tried to use `Output` but since components are from different modules it failed. I'm lost in what should I do. I want my "children" modules to send data to up the `app.module` to tell it if they needs a sidebar and which content should sidebar show. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter how the modules are related. What matters is, if the components are children in a components view. In this case you can use Angulars binding syntax. In other cases use a shared service. For details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

What also matters is, where you add a shared service as provider. If you add it to a component, only an instance of this component and its children and descendants share this service instance. 
If you add a service to providers of `@NgModule()` a single instance is shared with the whole application (for non-lazy loaded modules).

Comment: I tried to use Angular binding with Output but I din't have any selectors in my html, I just have `router-outlet`, how can I pass an event with that? And when I tried with selector jusn to test it I've got this error: `zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'child-selector' is not a known element:`

Comment: The child component needs to be added to `exports: []` in the NgModule` where it is in `declarations: []` and the current `NgModule` needs to have the other module in `imports: []`. Then binding with `<child-comp (xxx)="...">` should work. For components added by the router, there is no support for binding. For this case you need to use a shared service.

Comment: Thanks, then, I guess, shared service is for me.

Comment: But it looks like I can't rewrite my data in shared service. (I mean to make a service where every module's component will pass it's own data when link is navigated and app.component will take it to the sidebar menu.) Should I just make one service for my app.component and it'll change a content of sidebar menu depending on navigational link?

Comment: There are many possibilities so it's hard to say what you "should" do. If you have one sidebar a single service should do. Every component that wants to update the data shown in the sidebar should inject the the shared service and update its data (you can also use a router guard where you inject the service to do that https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, you can have a look at **[sharedModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module)**. **SharedModule** shares `services,pipes & etc` that you want to avail in different modules/components.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and tried `@Input()`, but it didn't work for me (the `@Input()` component reference being always `undefined`), probably because of unrelated components. Like this article suggests, shared service is probably the best approach for communicating components in different modules: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/communicating-across-components-using-services
I am pretty new to Angular and have spent almost 2 hours trying to find any easier way, but then I have set up a service in minutes.