# How to communicate components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm building an application with Angular 2 (in its most recent version), and I want to communicate between components.[image]

This is my workspace:

```
src
    app
        navbar
            navbar.component.ts
        footer
            footer.component.ts
        section
            dashboard
                dashboard.component.ts
            section.component.html
            section.component.ts
            section.module.ts
        sidebar
            sidebar.component.ts
        app.component.html
        app.module.ts
    assets
```

I want to call from the dashboard.component.ts a method in the footer.component.ts.

This is my code:

**footer.component.ts**

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  walking(){
    console.log("Method of called walking");
  }

}
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  callWalking(){
    console.log("Call to walking method");
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SectionComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SectionModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<app-section></app-section>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**section.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '**', component: DashboardComponent }
      ]
    )
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class SectionModule { }
```

**section.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**I literally want to call the "walk ()" method of component "footer.component.ts" from component dashboard.component.ts**

**How to call the "footer component> walk ()" method from the panel component method> callWalking ()?**

> In Java Android I can use static methods or implement buses for the
>   communication of activities or fragments, in angular I do not know
>   what I can do

Comment: What does callWalking actually do? If it's just a tool, I'd break it out into it's own class and pull it in everywhere you need it. You could also use input binding if you actually need to pass information between the two components: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: @DanWeber Does it work to pass data between different components? In the documentation says: Pass the data of the parents to the children with the incoming link, and my components are not parents and children. Or at least I do not know if they are, I think not :(.

Comment: They are all children (nested components) of the app component.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954785/different-module-components-communication-in-angular-2?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Build an Angular service to manage communication.**

**1. Create a service**

```
import { Injectable, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {



@Output() event$:EventEmitter<boolean>=new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { 

  }

  setEventEmitter(enable:boolean) {
      this.event$.next(enable);
  }

  getEventEmitter() {
     return this.event$;
  }  

}
```

**2. Set providers in app.module (Main module)**

```
....

providers: [TestService],

bootstrap: [AppComponent]

....
```

**3. Emit event**

```
constructor(private ls: TestService) { }

ngOnInit() {
      this.ls.setEventEmitter(true);  
}
```

**4. Receive event**

```
constructor(private ls: TestService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.ls.getEventEmitter().subscribe(e => {
        if(e != null) {
            console.log("Code here");
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about the purpose of the eventemitter in this example. I've found that I can simply access properties of the service and if they are bound, they will change appropriately ... no need to emit events. But I think I may be missing a use case? (My example without an eventEmitter is here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add @input and @output properties on the components. Then data can be passed from a component to its parent using an @output property and the parent can pass the info on to one of the other child components using its @input property.

A second option is to build an Angular service to manage the communication. Any component can call methods in the service and the other components can bind to service properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, your response has helped me find a good starting point. I decided to use option 2. Post my answer to this question, I would like to know if it is the best way, possibly there is a better way to do it.